# It's that time of year again

Tags: discussion, off-topic

## Merry Christmas everyone!

[image]

#### Been a good year on JSE :)

Comment: Thank you, same to you!

Comment: Thanks and same to you :)

Comment: Cheers! Merry Christmas and Happy New Year :)